# How to disable automatic checkpoint loading

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Im trying to run a loop over a set of parameters and I wan't to make a new network for each parameter and let it learn a few epochs.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
def optimize_scale(self, epochs=5, comp_scale=100, scale_list=[1, 100]):
    trainer = pyli.Trainer(gpus=1, max_epochs=epochs)
    
    for scale in scale_list:
        test_model = CustomNN(num_layers=1, scale=scale, lr=1, pad=True, batch_size=1)
        trainer.fit(test_model)
        trainer.test(verbose=True)
        
        del test_model
```

Everything works fine for the first element of `scale_list`, the network learns 5 epochs and completes the test. All this can be seen in the console. However for all following elements of `scale_list` it doesn't work as the old network is not overwritten, but instead an old checkpoint is loaded automatically when `trainer.fit(model)` is called. In the console this is indicated through:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\model_checkpoint.py:623: UserWarning:
Checkpoint directory D:\XXXX\src\lightning_logs\version_0\checkpoints exists and is not empty.
rank_zero_warn(f"Checkpoint directory {dirpath} exists and is not empty.")
train_size = 8   val_size = 1    test_size = 1
Restoring states from the checkpoint path at D:\XXXX\src\lightning_logs\version_0\checkpoints\epoch=4-step=39.ckpt
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
Loaded model weights from checkpoint at D:\XXXX\src\lightning_logs\version_0\checkpoints\epoch=4-step=39.ckpt
```

The consequence is that the second test outputs the same result, as the the checkpoint from the old network was loaded which already finished all 5 epochs. I though that adding the `del test_model` might help in dropping the model completely, but that did not work.

On my search I found a few Issues closely related, for example: https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/368. However I did not manage to fix my problem. I assume it has something to with the fact that the new network which should overwrite the old one has the same name/version and therefore looks for the same checkpoints.

If anyone has an idea or knows how to circumvent this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in your settings, you want to disable [automatic checkpointing](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/trainer.html#enable-checkpointing):

```py
trainer = pyli.Trainer(gpus=1, max_epochs=epochs,enable_checkpointing=False)
```

You may need to explicitly save a checkpoint (with a different name) for each training session you are running.

You can manually save a checkpoint via:

```py
trainer.save_checkpoint(f'checkpoint_for_scale_{scale}.pth')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This together with changing `trainer.test(verbose=True)` to `trainer.test(model=test_model, verbose=True)` made it work. Do you have by any chance an idea how to set the checkpoint name ? I haven't yet found it in the Trainer documentation.

Comment: @MEisebitt please see my update

Comment: I might have been too fast in saying it works. Interestingly each network learns now, but only the first one does epochs 0-4, all afterwards only do epoch 4 for some reason.

Comment: @MEisebitt I'm not very experienced with lightning, maybe you should create `Trainer` in each iteration?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it works. Sadly that does also make it slower, for that reason I wanted to have it outside the loop. However, thank you very much for your time and advises :)

Comment: @MEisebitt I guess you can dig into the internals of `Trainer` and find an "epoch counter" there you can adjust